# c++ mfc create maximum number an edit control can have

Tags: c++, mfc, numbers, max

with the following code i have managed to update edit control boxes with values on the click of a button.

```
void SomeDlg::OnBnClickedValue2Plus2()
{
    m_control1.GetWindowText(m_value1);
    m_control2.GetWindowText(m_value2);
    m_control3.GetWindowText(m_value3);
    int a,b,c;
    if (m_getcheck.GetCheck() == 1 
        && _ttoi(m_value2) < 40 
        && _ttoi(m_totalvalue) < 100)
    {
        a = _ttoi(m_value1);
        b = _ttoi(m_value2) + 2;
        c = a + b;
        GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText(_itot(b, buff, 10)); 
        GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT3)->SetWindowText(_itot(c, buff, 10));
    }
}

void SomeDlg::OnBnClickedValue3Plus3()
{
    m_control1.GetWindowText(m_value1);
    m_control2.GetWindowText(m_value2);
    m_control3.GetWindowText(m_value3);
    int a,b,c;
    if (m_getcheck.GetCheck() == 1 
        && _ttoi(m_value1) < 40 
        && _ttoi(m_totalvalue) < 100)
    {
        a = _ttoi(m_value1) + 3;
        b = _ttoi(m_value2);
        c = a + b;
        GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT2)->SetWindowText(_itot(a, buff, 10)); 
        GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT3)->SetWindowText(_itot(c, buff, 10));
    }
}
```

there are 3 edit controls that update when either plus2 or plus 3 button is pressed. when plus2 is pressed edit1 updates with +2, and when plus3 is pressed edit2 is updated with +3. the 3rd edit control displays the total number of edit1 + edit2 which should have a max of 100 with edit1, and edit2 having a maximum of 40.

however this is not the case, the values won't change if the number is the same or over the limit once the button is pressed, but if the value was 39 and i added 3 it would become 42 instead of 40 before becoming inactive .

how would i go about setting a maximum value for the edit controls?

Comment: Try and follow the code being executed by setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code lines.

Comment: Have you looked into the [dialog DDX/DDV mechanism](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14510/Dialog-Data-Exchange-in-MFC)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are checking the values before you modify them.
Simply change both "if" statments like this

```
if (m_getcheck.GetCheck() == 1 
    && (_ttoi(m_value2 ) + 2 ) <= 40 
    && (_ttoi(m_totalvalue ) + 2 ) <= 100)
```

And

```
if (m_getcheck.GetCheck() == 1 
    && ( _ttoi(m_value1 ) + 3 ) <= 40 
    && ( _ttoi(m_totalvalue) + 3 ) <= 100)
```

I also changed the < in <= because you said the MAX value for 1 and 2 is 40 and the total is 100.

Comment: that actually gave me the same problem. however, i solved the problem. thanks anyway.

Comment: Really? That's strange because I've checked this code in a demo project and actually it works. If you see in your solution you are doing absolutely the same I do: but you simply performe the increment in temporary variable insted do it directly in the IF statments ... I'm not sure if you tried correctly my code but doesn't care too much because you solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by changing

```
void SomeDlg::OnBnClickedValue3Plus3()
{
    m_control1.GetWindowText(m_value1);
    m_control2.GetWindowText(m_value2);
    m_control3.GetWindowText(m_value3);
    int a,b,c;
    if (m_getcheck.GetCheck() == 1 
        && _ttoi(m_value1) < 40 
        && _ttoi(m_totalvalue) < 100)
    {
        a = _ttoi(m_value1) + 3;
        b = _ttoi(m_value2);
        c = a + b;
        GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT2)->SetWindowText(_itot(a, buff, 10)); 
        GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT3)->SetWindowText(_itot(c, buff, 10));
    }    
}
```

to this

```
void SomeDlg::OnBnClickedValue3Plus3()
{
    m_control1.GetWindowText(m_value1);
    m_control2.GetWindowText(m_value2);
    m_control3.GetWindowText(m_value3);
    BOOL max1 = 40;
    BOOL max2 = 100;
    int a,b,c;
    a = _ttoi(m_value1) + 3;
    b = _ttoi(m_value2);
    c = a + b;

    if (m_getcheck.GetCheck() == 1 
        && a <= max1
        && c <= max2)
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT2)->SetWindowText(_itot(a, buff, 10)); 
        GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT3)->SetWindowText(_itot(c, buff, 10));
    }
}
```

this means when the value is 39, and i try to add 3 nothing happens. however, if i add 1 it reaches 40 which was the way i wanted to go in the first place, i just thought it would have been simpler if i had the number change to the max if i tried to add 3 to 39. turns out it was much easier to do it the way i originally intended. thanks for all the help.